# iOS URL Scheme Length

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme

Is there a limitation on the length of a URL Scheme for an iOS App?

We have a number of apps and want to prefix them with the name of our 14 character company name to prevent ambiguity.  I don't see any mention of a limitation in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) and I can enter an arbitrarily long string in Xcode.

I know that the shorter schemes are preferred but is there a limit on the length of the scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that its the [same as the normal URL scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).

This question goes over a similar topic, you might find more information in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680525/is-there-a-limit-on-the-size-of-the-variables-in-a-custom-url-handler).

Comment: The second and third links both point to the same SO question.  Was there another link?

Comment: @lambmj Nope, I just feel the need to put links whenever I type "here". Sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: Also, there is a MINIMUM URL scheme length. I noticed this after iOS 7 came out. Apple started rejecting URL schemes that are too short. 2 chars failed but 6 seems to work.